Specifying paketo ca-certificates parameters using spring boot maven plugin
On the paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates project, they provide 2 configurations using environment variable : BP_RUNTIME_CERT_BINDING_DISABLED and BP_ENABLE_RUNTIME_CERT_BINDING.
But I don't find any documentation to provide such properties from the maven configuration :

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <layout>JAR</layout>
                        <image>
                            <name>${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}</name>
                            <env>
                                <BPE_DELIM_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS xml:space="preserve"> </BPE_DELIM_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>
                                <BPE_APPEND_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>${WORKER_JVM_OPTION} -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
                                </BPE_APPEND_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS>
                                <!-- Add a healthcheck cli -->
                                <BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>true</BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>
                                <!-- Configure ca-certificates layer --><BP_RUNTIME_CERT_BINDING_DISABLED>true</BP_RUNTIME_CERT_BINDING_DISABLED>
                                <BP_ENABLE_RUNTIME_CERT_BINDING>false</BP_ENABLE_RUNTIME_CERT_BINDING>
                                <BP_EMBED_CERTS>true</BP_EMBED_CERTS>
                                <!-- Configure healthcheck cli to perform the healthcheck on specific port and path -->
                                <THC_PORT>9093</THC_PORT>
                                <THC_PATH>/actuator/health</THC_PATH>
                            </env>
                            <buildpacks>
                                <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java</buildpack>
                                <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates</buildpack>
                                <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:latest</buildpack>
                            </buildpacks>
                            <bindings>
                                <binding>
                                    ${binding.spring.location}/src/main/resources/ca-certificates/:/platform/bindings/ca-certificates
                                </binding>
                            </bindings>
                        </image>
                        <docker>
                            <publishRegistry>
                                <username>${docker.registry.user}</username>
                                <password>${docker.registry.password}</password>
                                <url>${docker.registry}</url>
                            </publishRegistry>
                        </docker>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

As you can see on the log, it does not work. There is no Build Configuration: on the ca-certificates module whereas the healthcheck module checks for its configuration parameter.

ExecutionEventLogger - --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.0:build-image (default-cli) @ file-extraction-worker ---
BuildImageForkMojo - Building image '172.26.x.x/file-extraction-worker:hotfixworker-ca-SNAPSHOT'
BuildImageForkMojo - 
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest' 100%
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base@sha256:1d242572b331e418bb201acac584322e05e911fedcfd6eb8c1af621b6875c102'
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base:latest' 100%
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base@sha256:fe8a63debed138c95a2c0ea1654bcbf493ab784e3f8e7c9f14ee522bac598c9e'
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Pulling buildpack image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:latest' 100%
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Pulled buildpack image 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker@sha256:267d1aac667b35647f8635996e90466fcf1ac0eea7b3bd7ebda8f25347acb3ce'
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Executing lifecycle version v0.19.7
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-b1dfe62ef508.build'
BuildImageForkMojo - 
BuildImageForkMojo -  > Running creator
BuildImageForkMojo - Layout: JAR
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     target distro name/version labels not found, reading /etc/os-release file
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     8 of 27 buildpacks participating
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates       3.8.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica     10.8.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft                  1.47.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar        6.10.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip              5.8.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot           5.30.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables 4.7.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/health-checker        1.17.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:helper" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:java-security-properties" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:jre" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/syft:syft" from cache
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:helper" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:spring-cloud-bindings" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:web-application-type" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables:environment-variables" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring metadata for "paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:thc" from app image
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Restoring data for "paketo-buildpacks/syft:syft" from cache
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     target distro name/version labels not found, reading /etc/os-release file
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.8.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       CA Certificates: Contributing to layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Embedding CA certificate(s)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Added 150 additional CA certificate(s) to system truststore
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.build/SSL_CERT_DIR.append
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.build/SSL_CERT_DIR.delim
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.build/SSL_CERT_FILE.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/SSL_CERT_DIR.append
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/SSL_CERT_DIR.delim
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/SSL_CERT_FILE.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     
.BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.8.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Build Configuration:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              17                                                           the Java version
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Using Java version 17 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 17.0.11: Contributing to layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/17.0.11+12/bellsoft-jre17.0.11+12-linux-amd64.tar.gz
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Verifying checksum
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Expanding to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jre
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Adding 287 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_APPLICATION_PATH.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_JVM_CACERTS.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_JVM_CLASS_COUNT.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPI_JVM_SECURITY_PROVIDERS.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_HOME.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.append
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.delim
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/MALLOC_ARENA_MAX.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/java-opts
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/jvm-heap
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/link-local-dns
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/memory-calculator
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/security-providers-configurer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/jmx
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/jfr
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/openssl-certificate-loader
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/security-providers-classpath-9
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/debug-9
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/helper/exec.d/nmt
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Java Security Properties: Contributing to layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_SECURITY_PROPERTIES.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.append
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.delim]
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Syft 1.47.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/syft
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/anchore/syft/releases/download/v0.105.1/syft_0.105.1_linux_amd64.tar.gz
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Verifying checksum
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.build/SYFT_CHECK_FOR_APP_UPDATE.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Executable JAR 6.10.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Command "packages" is deprecated, use `syft scan` instead
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env/CLASSPATH.delim
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env/CLASSPATH.prepend
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Process types:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         executable-jar: java org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher (direct)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         task:           java org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher (direct)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         web:            java org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher (direct)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Spring Boot 5.30.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Build Configuration:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_CDS_ENABLED                 false  whether to enable CDS optimizations at runtime
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_AOT_ENABLED              false  whether to enable Spring AOT at runtime
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_JVM_CDS_ENABLED                  false  whether to enable CDS & perform JVM training run
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_AOT_ENABLED               false  whether to enable Spring AOT
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED   false  whether to contribute Spring Boot cloud bindings support
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_VERSION    1      default version of Spring Cloud Bindings library to contribute
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED  false  whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED   true   Deprecated - whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Creating slices from layers index
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         dependencies (103.7 MB)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         spring-boot-loader (399.5 KB)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         snapshot-dependencies (425.5 KB)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         application (433.7 KB)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Spring Cloud Bindings 2.0.3: Reloading cached layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Downloading from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/2.0.3/spring-cloud-bindings-2.0.3.jar
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Verifying checksum
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Copying to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_spring-boot/spring-cloud-bindings
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Web Application Type: Contributing to layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Servlet web application detected
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Writing env.launch/BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT.default
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_spring-boot/helper/exec.d/spring-cloud-bindings
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       4 application slices
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Image labels:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         org.springframework.boot.version
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Environment Variables 4.7.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPE_<NAME>           prepend value to $NAME, delimiting with OS path list separator
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPE_APPEND_<NAME>    append value to $NAME
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPE_DEFAULT_<NAME>   set default value for $NAME
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPE_DELIM_<NAME>     set delimeter to use when appending or prepending to $NAME
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPE_OVERRIDE_<NAME>  set $NAME to value
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BPE_PREPEND_<NAME>   prepend value to $NAME
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Environment Variables: Reusing cached layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Health Checkers 1.17.0
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Build Configuration:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_DEPENDENCY  thc   which health checker to contribute
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         $BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED     true  contributes a health checker if enabled
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Tiny Health Checker 0.27.0: Reusing cached layer
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]       Process types:
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]         health-check: thc (direct)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     ===> EXPORTING
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates:ca-certificates'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:helper'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:java-security-properties'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:jre'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar:classpath'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:helper'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:spring-cloud-bindings'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:web-application-type'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables:environment-variables'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Reusing layer 'paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:thc'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:launch.sbom'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding 5/5 app layer(s)
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:launcher'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:config'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Reusing layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:process-types'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding label 'org.springframework.boot.version'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Setting default process type 'web'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Saving 172.26.x.x/file-extraction-worker:hotfixworker-ca-SNAPSHOT...
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     *** Images (dc7bdb0f6642):
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]           172.26.x.x/file-extraction-worker:hotfixworker-ca-SNAPSHOT
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/syft:syft'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding cache layer 'paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot:spring-cloud-bindings'
BuildImageForkMojo -     [creator]     Adding cache layer 'buildpacksio/lifecycle:cache.sbom'
BuildImageForkMojo - 
BuildImageForkMojo - Successfully built image '172.26.x.x/file-extraction-worker:hotfixworker-ca-SNAPSHOT'

Any idea where the issue is ? I don't know how to start with all theses project linked together
